# PHP API CReate Private Event

Tags: php, api, events, facebook-graph-api, private

Hi Im trying to create private events from an App

I can create the invite, invite friends etc fine but i cant get the event to be created as private (invite only)

The params i use to create the event are

```
$event_param = array(
    "name" => "Event Name",
"start_time" => $nextWeek,
"location" => $where,
"privacy" => 'CLOSED',
"description" => $description
);
```

In the privacy option have tried 'PRIVATE', 'CLOSED' and 'SECRET' but all create a public event.

I have been granted the following permissions

```
user_about_me,
user_birthday,
read_friendlists,
publish_stream,
read_stream,
email,
create_event,
rsvp_event,
user_events,
friends_events
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `field` for privacy settings called `privacy_type` (not `privacy`).

Comment: thanks worked perfectly, still cant find that in the documentation

Comment: @GafferG, voila: [User's events](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events), [Page Events](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although Facebook documentation says "privacy" it should be "privacy_type".

Example;

```
$statusUpdate = $facebook->api("/$user/events", 'post', array(
            'name' => $your_event_title,
            'description' => $your_event_description,
            'start_time' => $start_date_event,
            'privacy_type' => $privacy_type,
            'owner' => $your_facebook_user_id,
            'location'=> $location_of_event));
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        d($e);
    }
```

Find more about creating events in the Facebook documentation.

DOCS: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/